# Representing data in combination of QAM and BPSK

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, demodulation

I have a question regarding the data representation in different modulations. Assuming we are using MIMO system whith $4$ $T_x$ x $4$ $R_x$  which means four transmission antennas by four receiving antennas. My question, if three antennas are using QAM modulation, and the other antenna uses BPSK modulation. Is it possible the Receiving antennas can distinguish the data sent from each antennas ? I mean is it possible to detect the data sent from transmission antennas?

I'm asking that because in QAM modulation, data will be represented with real and imaginary parts, where in BPSK, data will be represented in real part only. So I see it logic that receiving antenna can detect the data perfectly. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that is possible. As you said, the three first antenna will be using QAM where the other antenna will be using BPSK. In that case, I advise you to read about Spatial modulation (SM), and Generalized Spatial modulation (GSM), Quadrature Spatial modulation (QSM) and finally the newest paper I've ever seen is F-QSM. All those papers are talking about MIMO, to be more specific, they are talking about the alternative approach of MIMO which is SM. If you want to go further, the same purpose was also implemented for OFDM resulting the OFDM-IM. It's a very good area to study and search.

In general, the new SM, is how to use the index of antennas in order to transmit more bits which will improve the spectral efficiency.

Regarding to the answer coming from Marcus !!, I think Adding up the QAM-based modulation with BPSK-based modulation will not happen as long as you are transmitting that on different antennas, "Exactly as you've said in your question". Secondly, the channels should usually be uncorrelated, so interference can be entirely avoided.

In such new articles, such that Quadrature spatial modulation, that can work as long as the signal transmitted on antennas are orthogonal. So, interference can be entirely avoided too.

You are good, just keep going on. and if you needed any help, you'd write it as a question here, many people are helping and they will try to help you too.

thank you.

Comment: Your answer is wrong: In a MIMO channel, the transmissions of multiple antennas *do* add up. That's how MIMO works. And that's why you represent such channels as (non-diagonal) channel matrix, to be multiplied with the transmit signals vector.

Comment: With Spatial Modulation you're bringing in a different topic. The whole beauty of spatial modulation is that you're getting effects that you'd usually only get when doing MIMO, but without having multiple simultaneously active transmit chains. If you use different modulations for different antennas, you're not only embedding bits into the antenna choice, but also the modulation choice. Not quite sure this is a smart move, because typically, you'd assume that all antennas are realizations of the same stochastic process that yields channels, so that all the things you'd decide which

Comment: … constellation to pick would be the same (unless you have apriori CSI on the transmitter, which opens up a whole can of other questions about why you're using SM). So, one of these antennas would then be using an unnecessarily suboptimal constellation. I can't imagine a case where this would be desirable – if the channels are similar enough so that you need a different constellation just to tell the active antenna apart, why not do that for a single antenna and get even more bits across. Do you have a paper that quantifies the advantages of SM + different constellations?

Comment: Why you always change the subject into MIMO !!! I said many times, in that case SM, GSM and others should be read. Anyway, that question might take long discussion, the New_student can search and asks others and let us know. I really can't explain more than I did. I talked about GSM, SM, and QSM. and you are still talking about SM. SM is different about GSM and QSM where just only one antenna is active, GSM and QSM one OR more antennas can be active. What I said that in his case, he should look at SM and its new versions instead of MIMO. what he said represents the case of QSM more than MIMO.

Comment: I asked some professors at my university, They confirmed that in case of GSM and SM, that can be done but symbols must be transmitted in different time. they said in each instant the antennas are active, they should use one modulation. . I think I'll agree on that.

Comment: "why always MIMO": Because OP literally wrote in his second sentence: *Assuming we are using MIMO system*. Not a change of subject, I adhere to the subject at hand.

Comment: And: say hello to the professors at your university from me :) Because they agree with my assessment from my comment above that if you have multiple antennas transmitting at the same time, they should have the same modulation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller .. it's finished. we are here to help. we are not here to loose time and enjoy criticizing people and argue.  Give up,   everyone here is busy. to New_student, please try to choose the best answer for you and then ask your professors or others.

Comment: @Zeyad_Zeyad I must admit that while I'm definitely not here to argue, wrong anwers still are worth criticizing. And your answer is still wrong in that on the channel the BPSK and QAM **will** add up. Not even QSM claims to remedy that, as QAM has both real and imaginary part.

Answer (score 2):

Let's us take the simple case $2\times 2$ MIMO. Let $y_1$, and $y_2$ be the received signal at the first and second receive antennas, respectively. Then we have

$$y_1 = h_{11}x_1 + h_{21}x_2 + n_1$$

and

$$y_2 = h_{12}x_1 + h_{22}x_2 + n_2$$

where $h_{ij}$ is the channel coefficient from transmit antenna $i$ to receive antenna $j$, $x_i$ is the transmitted signal from transmit antenna $i$, and $n_i$ is the AWGN at receive antenna $i$.

We can write the above signals in matrix-vector form as

$$\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{H}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{n}$$

Apparently, there is interference here. So, we need to do some sort of equalization. Let's use zero forcing (ZF) for simplicity. In this case you get

$$\mathbf{H}^{-1}\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{\tilde{x}}=\left[\begin{matrix} \tilde{x}_1\\\tilde{x}_2\end{matrix}\right]$$

where $$\tilde{x}_i = x_i + \tilde{n}_i$$

for $i = 1,\,2$.

Now, suppose that $x_1$ is 4-QAM, and $x_2$ is BPSK, both have the same symbol time. Will that be a problem? and why? They seem separable to me, and can be detected given that the receiver knows in advance that $x_1$ is drawn from a 4-QAM constellation, while $x_2$ from a BPSK constellation. Actually we do this in OFDM. It's called bit loading, where different subcarriers are modulated with different modulation sizes, and schemes when the CSI is know at the transmitter. Of course in OFDM the symbols are separable because of the orthogonality of the subcarriers, but we can somehow separate the signals in spatial multiplexing, although not perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much ..  I also asked professor, he replied me by the same thing. he said we can do it as long as the antenna are different, and he advised be to read about Dual-OFDM. he said it's new article, but I didn't get it :( .. you mean you agree with answer coming fomr Zeyad_Zeyad ??

Comment: @New_student I don't know about spatial modulation, which is different than spatial multiplexing by the way. My answer is different I believe. I am not sure how interference can be avoided completely in spatial modulation. For example I don't agree with this statement, at least as it is "I think Adding up the QAM-based modulation with BPSK-based modulation will not happen as long as you are transmitting that on different antennas, ..". As long as we transmit different signals on different antennas at the same time, interference is inevitable. He needs to elaborate on his answer more, I think

Comment: Fully agreeing with you! Zeyad's answer as it's written is wrong, and the fact that (Q)SM is proposed doesn't remedy that at all.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You commented "if you have multiple antennas transmitting at the same time, they should have the same modulation", why is that again? Why cannot you have different modulations on different antennas? They will add up, but you can separate them by equalization, and then detect each symbol based on the modulation scheme it used. I think my derivation shows that, doesn't it?

Comment: @BlackMath well, the process of choosing a modulation depends on how you model the channel. The Antenna models underlying all these SM papers say that all channels are realizations of random process that share the same properties.In other words,if you choose modulation A for one antenna because it's a good modulation for the channel you're expecting,it's bound to be a good constellation for the other antenna,too. So, if you choose another constellation,you're bound to either do something that is impossible to tell from the first constellation and hence can't carry bits, or strongly suboptimal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Why choosing one good constellation for one antenna means the same constellation is good for other antennas if the channels from different transmit antennas are independent? But this is not the question: the question is in theory can we do it? In my analysis, cannot we assume that $x_1$ is from one modulation scheme/size, and $x_2$ is from another modulation scheme/size? and why?

Comment: In theory you can do a lot! But as I tried to explain: You don't know your transmit channels. Hence, you need to make a stochastic model of them. In those models, you say "all the channels are different, but they come from the same random model with the same moments". Based on that model, you find the appropriate constellation. You don't just use "any" constellation! But since that model is the same for all channels, you'd do the same choice for all of them.Also note that I have my doubts that in the typical application for SM,you'll have an easy way of telling different constellations apart.

Comment: @MarcusMüller In theory doesn't mean wish to do. It's based on mathematics. I still don't get your justification. I think the signals at different receive antennas sum up, but after equalization we can separate them sub-optimally. I don't see how channel models are relevant here. The receiver can estimate the channels, and equalize it.

Comment: @BlackMath..Yes I agree. I mean transmitting symbols in different antenna with different time. for example int $t1$ you will transmit the information based on such constellation, and in $t2$ you can change the constellation type and so on, that's normal. Marcus usually doesn't focus on question, he just criticize members and give then negative feedback, I've seen many of his comments (almost 90%) where he doesn't reply the question more than giving bad feelings for members including this coment (before modification), the answer was 2 lines and Criticizing in 7 lines.we are here just to help

Comment: @Zeyad_Zeyad If we transmit different symbols over different times, then that has nothing to do with MIMO. The question was about spatial multiplexing MIMO where we transmit different symbols (possibly from different constellations) over different transmit antennas at the same time. My answer is yes, given that the receiver knows the modulation scheme from each transmit antenna, and that all symbols have the same symbol time.

Comment: @BlackMath .. Yes,  but I've already mentioned in my answer, if he wants to use that technique in perfect way, so he should use SM "Spatial modulation" instead of traditional known MIMO .. that's right.

Comment: @BlackMath Ok, so, if your channels are "about the same", i.e. $\text{Var}(|h|)$ isn't that large, and you'd be free to choose the constellation for these channels, wouldn't that always be the same constellation that leads to the highest throughput? Stupid example:  if you *can* use 256-QAM on two antennas (large $|h|$ on both), but choose to use 256-QAM on one and BPSK on the other, you'd be loosing 7 bits of capacity per channel usage in constellation cardinality, but gained 1 bit because you were able to pick the constellation. That's a bad trade. I've been sitting here and trying to find

Comment: @BlackMath … constellations that are *robust enough* to tell apart, because a misdetected constellation wouldn't only damage that one bit transported in the constellation choice, but still both have less than one bit of information capacity difference. That seems impossible. I'm trying to work on a Constellation norm definition to prove that.

Comment: @BlackMath from a math perspective: you need a lot of mutual information to estimate the constellation used. If you have that mutual information between TX and RX, better invest it in higher constellations.

Answer (score -2):

No, they *can't* simply tell things apart. How should they?

On the air, the transmitted QAM-based signal adds up with the BPSK signal, and even in the exact symbol times, you get numbers with real and imaginary part.

Also, you forget that signals still are pulse shaped; a sensible pulse shaper can have a complex part when going from one BPSK symbol to the other.

What you describe has nothing to do with how MIMO works! MIMO works because for uncorrelated channels, you can find a matrix decomposition of your $\mathbb C^{N_{TX}\times N_{RX}}$ (flat channel case) matrix, not because the signals are different. With that matrix decomposition, you can find "separable" channels, even though the signals add up "on the air" and you just receive a mishmash of all TX signals at each RX antenna (though the amount of the TX signals in that mishmash has to be different for each RX antenna).

Because Zeyad_Zeyad introduces SM but doesn't agree on whether in a MIMO channel, signals from different antennas sum in the air:

The typical MIMO channel is modeled like this:

[image]

With each RX antenna seeing a linear combination of all TX signals; hence, the representation as channel matrix $\mathbf H$

$$\mathbf H=\begin{pmatrix}
h_{11} & h_{12} & h_{13}\\
h_{21} & h_{22} & h_{23}\\
h_{31} & h_{32} & h_{33}
\end{pmatrix}$$

so that you can get the first receive signal as the first entry, the second as the second entry, … of

$$\vec r =\mathbf H \vec t\text,$$

where $\vec t$ is the transmit signal vector (i.e. the first entry is the symbol at TX antenna 1, the second at TX antenna 2 …).

As you can see, if say $t_1$ is real but $t_2$ or $t_3$ have an imaginary part, $r_1$ can very well be complex.

So, as you can see, for MIMO to work, you don't need the signals to have different characteristics – you need the *channel coefficients* $h_{i,j}$ to be independent enough!

---

Please allow me a personal note from the perspective of someone who helps students survive exams in "Digital Communications Basics" courses at university, @Eng. Badr:

In your previous questions, you were wildly jumping from extremely involved topics like FBMC to more entry-level topics like CDMA then down to the very, very basic of QAM vs PSK (which you had a great misunderstanding about!). Now you're back to a topic that is relatively complex (MIMO) and requires solid understanding of the things like constellations.

You sound like a student who's either preparing for an exam for which they are missing the basic course, or like someone doing a thesis on a topic where they have to acquire basic knowledge by themselves. In either case, jumping into topics, asking a single question, and then jumping to the next topic will not enable you to understand much, and cost very much of your time, without enabling you to do your own deductions. Especially in the thesis case, that's a hazard, because at some point, someone will point at a blaring mistake in what you're doing and say "ok, every person who works on {topic} should know that this can't work, it's really basic".

So, do *yourself* the favor of getting a digital communications textbook that takes you from the basics of complex baseband over constellations, pulse shaping, a tiny bit of channel coding, over to multi-access schemes like FDMA and CDMA and finally MIMO. I promise that in the medium run, reading that book from start to finish *will save you time and effort* and, if my hypothesis on the situation you're in is right, will definitely improve the grade you'll be getting.

Comment: They are not going to be added up since the transmission is on different antennas. Clarify your answer . !!

Comment: But they are. That's the beauty of MIMO.

Comment: Yes, after those modifications you have done, It seems little be ok. I might agree with you. but excuse me to tell you that your answer before that modification is completely wrong.

Comment: What. No. That's not true, sorry. You can go into the edit history and see that I didn't *change* anything. I just copy/pasted the *definition* of the MIMO channel here.